# Noindex in head

Tags: php, head, noindex

my head looks like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7phmhirwzcrzvp3/head.php?dl=0
I want to add noindex,follow to certain pages and I have tried adding this

```
    <?php if($paged > 1 || is_archive || is_404 ||is_page(array( 2,4,6 ))){echo '<meta name="robots"content="noindex,follow" />'; } ?>
```

but then ALL my pges except the homepage are set to noindex,follow...can someone tell me if I need to change the code or where exactly I would need to put it??

Comment: `is_archive` probably will return always false because you didnt define th constant? or `$paged` != `$page` ... what is `is_page()`? Need more information, problem is not reproducable.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the variables and constants you use do not contain the stuff you expect them to.

Your best choice is to iterate your conditions until. Starting with…

```
<?php if($paged > 1){echo '<meta name="robots"content="noindex,follow" />'; } ?>
```

…going to…

```
<?php if($paged > 1 || is_archive){echo '<meta name="robots"content="noindex,follow" />'; } ?>
```

…and so on.

Oh, and have a look at your error log. `is_archive` looks like a constant, but you might mean `is_archive()` or `$is_archive`. Your error log might reveal such issues - even more so, if you set `error_reporting(E_STRICT);` to be especially picky about unset variables.

Another way would be `var_dump();` for every variable you want to use in your condition, for you to check what content is in your variables. Like:

```
<?php var_dump(array($paged > 1,is_archive, is_404,is_page(array( 2,4,6 )))); ?>
```

Comment: fboes, if i add the var_dump, no page is getting noindex at all. I am not experienced in programming at all...would it be better to put this in a function somehow?

Comment: The idea is, that `var_dump` tells you the content of your given variables. Just past the `var_dump`-line into your HTML, and you will see if your condition is met. Otherwise I strongly recommend turning on error reporting and observing errors in your error log.